# How to display the Lookup icon automatically to select Opportunity on a custom visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

My expectation is to display lookup icon next to Opportunity field. The results  received from custom class in controller.

I am trying to display the opportunity name, but am expecting to display with lookup icon next to it which allows user to select another opportunity. My intention is update the record with another opportunity if user decides to do.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!result.oppty.Name}"/>

public class SearchResultController {
    public List<SearchResult> resultList {get; set;}
    public SearchResult searchResult {get; set;}

    public SearchResultController() {
    searchResult = new SearchResult();
    getSearchResults();
    }

    public class SearchResult {
        public Id acctId {get; set;}
        public Opportunity oppty {get; set;}
    }

    public void getSearchResults() {
       // populate resultList.
    }
```

}

Expected: SearchResults displayed using pageBlockTable. Display lookup icon next to opportunity name.

Answer (score 0):

One way we found the solution is below:

- Create an object (kind of dummy object) with all the lookup fields that we wanted. Add it to the Controller as instance variable.
- In UI, display this dummy object with opportunity which automatically displays the standard look up icon and functionality.
- Once user selects the opportunity values and saves / submits, map the dummy object ID into SearchResult object's oppty in the Controller.